# Understanding LDO Dropout

Tags: voltage-regulator, linear-regulator

Disclaimer: Super newbie and first time poster here.

The [MCP1700 LDO regulator](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/268/MCP1700-Low-Quiescent-Current-LDO-20001826E-737536.pdf) datasheet states on p3 that the Droptout voltage is 350mV for Vout > 2.5V @ I=250mA. I thought great I can power my ESP32 from an 18650 battery. 3.7V - .35V = 3.35V. Works out perfectly! Well it doesn't. The regulator's Vout kept dipping below 2.5V and the ESP32 kept browning out.

I couldn't understand this until I went back and read the datasheet, carefully this time, and saw this note 5: `Dropout voltage is defined as the input to output differential at which the output voltage drops 2% below its measured value with a VR+ 1V differential applied.`

My question: If I need a whole extra 1V for the regulator to properly work, then why tell me that the drop out is 350mV? What's the significance of this information? I came across the same thing with multiple regulators so I must be missing something.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know the actual load current? Have you decoupled the input and output as required?

Comment: The 1 V extra is just a **reference point** to **measure** the dropout voltage. With a 3.3 V regulator, then 3.3 V **+ 1 V** = 4.3 V is applied. Then the output voltage is measured, it will be around 3.3 V. Let's say it is 3.305 V. Now we lower the input voltage slowly until Vout has dropped 2%, that is when Vout = 3.305 V - 2% = 3.239 V. Then Vdropout = Vin - Vout.

Comment: *The LDO output is stable when using only 1µF output capacitance.* What input/output capacitors did you use? .. as @PeterSmith also asked. An oscillating output may have fried your ESP32.

Comment: The ESP draws current in a spikey manner- have you confirmed the actual input voltage dips  under load with an oscilloscope?

Comment: Yep I used capacitors just like described in the datasheet. 1uF Cin and 1uF Cout. I also tried adding an electrolytic capacitor 47uF.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Yes. It happens when I turn on WiFi which draws 150mA according to the multimeter. I bought a scope and put the probes on Vbatt and Vout from the regulator. Vbatt was stable at ~ 4V (fully charged 18650). Vout varied. I had a Math function of Vbatt- Vout on the scope which went from 350mV to 1V when load increased to 150mA which is still within the regulator's limit.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie ahhh I think I understand. So yes, they're saying that if my setup has a 1V differential will be 350mV but it's just a reference. They're *not* saying that if the differential is less that it won't work. They just didn't measure it. Is that it?

Comment: Given all the answers and now that I think of it, maybe ESP is drawing over 250mA on wifi startup but the multimeter doesn't sample quickly enough. When that happens the regulator would be trying to compensate for the transient load, which leads to a higher Vdiff but ultimately hits its 250mA current limit and shuts down for an instant which causes the brownout. I will buy a current probe and look at the current in the scope instead of the MM. It'll take a few days. I'll come back with the answer. Thanks everyone!

Comment: @user6545685 *Is that it?* Uhm, no, you have to read my comment carefully. The 1 V Vdrop is just a **measurement condition** that they use as a **reference**. Just forget about that 1 V, the minimum voltage drop is the 350 mV. Your issue isn't related to that anyway, it is the **peak current** that the ESP draws causing the voltage to drop too low.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie thanks. You were right. I just had to read it in a different way. Not sure why it only clicked when I read the paper though it's saying the same thing you did.

Answer (score 1):

Alright so I think I found a clear explanation for that statement. According to [this paper](http://www.ti.com/download/trng/docs/seminar/Topic%209%20-%20Understanding%20LDO%20dropout.pdf) one test method is to:

> measure the output voltage   when   VIN   is   1   V   above   the   nominal   output  voltage  and  then  load  the  LDO  with  the  specified  test  current.  The  input  voltage  is  then  reduced  until  VOUT  drops  by  a  specified  number  of  millivolts.  For  example,  4.3  V  is  applied  to  a  3.3-V   LDO.   The   output   voltage   is   measured   (assuming at 3.3 V), and then the input voltage is reduced  until  the  output  voltage  measures  3.2  V.  Dropout is defined as the input voltage minus the output  voltage  at  this  point.  If  VIN  =  3.5  V  when  VOUT  =  3.2  V,  the  LDO  has  a  300-mV  dropout  voltage. An LDO tested in this method will have a note similar to that shown below.
>
> “Dropout     voltage     is     defined     as     the     differential  voltage  between  VOUT and  VIN  when  VOUT  drops  100  mV  below  the  value  measured  with VIN = VOUT + 1 V “

In the datasheet I was reading the manufacturer opted to use 2% or 66mv in the case of 3.3V as opposed to the 100mv in the example above.

As for my specific application, I replaced the regulator with one rated for 500mA. The new one is working perfectly. I will wait for my current probe to see using my scope how much exactly is the ESP spiking. It seems like such a quick spike over 250mA that my MM's Max function can't catch it.